# A short way to wrap class's static member variable

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-meta-programming, sfinae

Imagine that you have several classes and all of them contain a static variable of the same meaning, but it's names differ in different classes.

A toy example:

```
class Point2D
{
public:
    static constexpr int dimension = 2;
private:
    double x, y;
} 

class Point3D
{
public:
    static constexpr int dim = 3;
private:
    double x, y, z;
};
```

I want to wrap a "dimension" variable with a `std::integral_constant`'s child. Note that I can't edit 'Point' classes, because they are parts of some external libraries. This implementation works for me, but looks clumsy (I'm using VS2017):

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct HasDimensionVar : std::false_type { };
template <typename T>
struct HasDimensionVar<T, decltype( T::dimension, void( ) )> : std::true_type { };

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct HasDimVar : std::false_type { };
template <typename T>
struct HasDimVar<T, decltype( T::dim, void( ) )> : std::true_type { };

template <typename T, class Enable = void>
struct Dimension;

template <typename T>
struct Dimension<T, std::enable_if_t< HasDimensionVar<T>::value> > :
    std::integral_constant<decltype( T::dimension ), T::dimension> { };

template <typename T>
struct Dimension<T, std::enable_if_t< HasDimVar<T>::value> > :
    std::integral_constant<decltype( T::dim ), T::dim> { };
```

Is there a way to skip all these `HasSomeVars` and have something short and clear like this:

```
template <typename T, class Enable = void>
struct Dimension;

template <typename T>
struct Dimension<T, decltype( T::dimension, void( ) ) > :
    std::integral_constant<decltype( T::dimension ), T::dimension> { };

template <typename T>
struct Dimension<T, decltype( T::dim, void( ) ) > :
    std::integral_constant<decltype( T::dim ), T::dim> { };
```

This code gets a compile error:

> Error C2953:  'Dimension< T, unknown-type >': class template has already been defined

Comment: Seems to be [a known problem](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/06/07/expression-sfinae-improvements-in-vs-2015-update-3/) with expression SFINAE implementation in MSVC.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, so my last code snippet is correct, but doesn't compile because of MSVC internal issues?

Comment: Still, is there a nicer solution that will work with MSVC 2017?

Comment: This really sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What do you want to do? If you just want to retrieve the value, indirect through a template specialization

Comment: @PasserBy Oh my, I tried not to overload my question with extra info.:) I want to implement a class that works with many different kinds of 'Points' (both internal and external). I need to get 'dimension' value at compile time. But I want to free the user of setting dimension (for example, with a template parameter) for common 'Point' types (nevertheless, he will need to set it for other types). Here comes 'Dimension' wrapper. And I want to smoothen my solution for it. What do you think should be added to my question?

Comment: I have no idea. I only have the feeling you are trying to solve another problem in a convoluted way.

Comment: @PasserBy, I scanned through your link and my current solution once more. No, I don't think there is a XY-problem, cause the only thing I want to know here whether Has...Var can be omited or not, they look like something unnecessary. Let's think there's nothing else around the given piece of code. I just want to know whether I miss a cleaner implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that while MSVC is getting better and better, there are still a few cases of expression SFINAE that it can't quite deal with with. So we just gotta help it out a little bit. Instead of trying to specialize the same class template or provide two different functions with the same signature, we can just provide two *different* functions and overload on them:

```
namespace detail {
    template <typename T>
    constexpr std::integral_constant<decltype(T::dim), T::dim>
    get_dimensions(int)
    {
        return {};
    }

    template <typename T>
    constexpr std::integral_constant<decltype(T::dimension), T::dimension>
    get_dimensions(long)
    {
        return {};
    }
}
```

It doesn't seem like MSVC supports `template<auto>` yet, so you'll just have to repeat the name twice. With that, we can just alias the appropriate result:

```
template <typename T>
using Dimension = decltype(detail::get_dimensions<T>(0));
```

This compiles for me with the latest MSVC on godbolt (as well as gcc and clang).

Comment: That's a trick! Thank you, Barry, it compiles for me too. The only question is what if we run out of arithmetic types?:)

Comment: @Barry, I like your solution. However, using Type2Type (by Alexandrescu) instead of arithmetic types seems cleaner, and you don't need to worry about running out of types. It is defined like this: `template<typename T> struct Type2Type { typedef T OriginalType; };`. Then, it is used as the parameter for all overloads: `get_dimensions(Type2Type<T>)`. Finally, Dimension would be defined like this: `template<typename T> using Dimension = decltype(get_dimensions<T>(Type2Type<T>()));`

Comment: @LuisGuzman I'm not sure how that helps. And I don't have to worry about running out of types, see that blog.

Answer (score 1):

And now... for something completely different...

You could define a couple of `getDim()` template `constexpr`, SFINAE enabled/disabled, functions.

One for types with `dim`

```
template <typename T>
constexpr auto getDim () -> decltype( T::dim )
 { return T::dim; }
```

and one for types with `dimension`

```
template <typename T>
constexpr auto getDim () -> decltype( T::dimension )
 { return T::dimension; }
```

You can add other template functions if needed.

Now your `Dimension` template class become directly

```
template <typename T>
struct Dimension
   : std::integral_constant<decltype(getDim<T>()), getDim<T>()>
 { };
```

or also, if you want do give a different name to the variable

```
template <typename T>
struct Dimension
 {
   static constexpr auto dim { getDim<T>() };
 };
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <iostream>

class Point2D
 {
   public:
      static constexpr int dimension = 2;

   private:
      double x, y;
 };

class Point3D
 {
   public:
      static constexpr int dim = 3;

   private:
      double x, y, z;
 };


template <typename T>
constexpr auto getDim () -> decltype( T::dim )
 { return T::dim; }

template <typename T>
constexpr auto getDim () -> decltype( T::dimension )
 { return T::dimension; }

template <typename T>
struct Dimension
   : std::integral_constant<decltype(getDim<T>()), getDim<T>()>
 { };

int main()
 {
   Dimension<Point2D>  d2; // compile
   Dimension<Point3D>  d3; // compile

   //Dimension<int>  di;  // compilation error

   static_assert( Dimension<Point2D>::value == 2, "!" );
   static_assert( Dimension<Point3D>::value == 3, "!" );
 }
```

Comment: It's a nice solution, thank you, Max! But it also produces a compile error in MSVC: 'Error C2995 'unknown-type getDim(void)': function template has already been defined'

Comment: @SheiladePope - You get the error from my example or from a different code? It's possible that you have a type with both `dim` and `dimension`? In this case, you should follow the Barry's way (a function that receive a type; another function that receive another type) to avoid "collisions".

Comment: @SheiladePope - OK: I surrender. I can argue with C++ but fighting against MSVC is too difficult for me.

Answer (score -1):

Although this is not a good approach, but this will work for you:

```
#define DEFVAR(nm,val) static constexpr int nm = val;

class Point2D
{
public:
    DEFVAR(dimension,2)
private:
    double x, y;
};

class Point3D
{
public:
    DEFVAR(dim,3)
private:
    double x, y, z;
};
```

Comment: Oh yes, this will work, but I can't change 'Point' classes (because some of them are part of external libraries). Nevertheless, thanks for your answer, I will update my question.